# Change variable during runtime

Tags: forms, events, f#, mutable

I have an enum:

```
type Tool = 
    | Rectangle = 0
    | Circle = 1
```

And a variable to hold a enum value:

```
let mutable selectedTool : Tool = Tool.Rectangle
```

I have two buttons:

```
let btn (location:Point) (size:Size) =
    let bt = new Button()
    do bt.Location <- location
    do bt.Size <- size
    bt
// These badboys right here:
let rectangleButton = btn (Point(0, 0)) (Size(50,50))
let ellipseButton = btn (Point(50, 0)) (Size(50,50))
```

They each have an event connected to them:

```
let btnRectEvent = rectangleButton.Click.Add(fun(x) -> selectedTool <-Tool.Rectangle)
let btnElliEvent = ellipseButton.Click.Add(fun(x) -> selectedTool <- Tool.Circle)
```

**I want my events to change the value of the selectedTool variable.**
Currently, it doesen't work.
I then record my MouseDown event on my drawing area to draw a shape using this event:

```
let mouseEvent =
    let x = selectedTool
    form.MouseDown
    |> Event.add ( fun (evArgs1) -> 
            if x = Tool.Circle then
                graphics.Graphics.DrawEllipse(whitePen, evArgs1.X, evArgs1.Y, 15, 15)
            else 
                graphics.Graphics.DrawRectangle(whitePen, evArgs1.X, evArgs1.Y, 15, 15)
            form.Refresh())
```

form is running as follows:

```
form.Controls.Add(rectangleButton)
form.Controls.Add(ellipseButton)

form.Show()
while form.Created do
    Application.DoEvents()
```

Bonus Question but not in need of answering:
Is it possible to catch a click event on the button, wait for a mousedown event on the drawing area, place the first corner of my shape, have a preview of the shape when I'm moving my mouse around, and set the second corner on mouseUp, in an not-too-overkill way?

TL;DR bonus question: Can I easily make the rectangledrawing work like in MSPaint?

Comment: Why aren't you using `Application.Run(new form())`?  Also, try putting printf in the events

Comment: Because I did not know of it's existence. Thank you :)
Also, I did put the following in to test if the events did anything: rectangleButton.Click.Add(fun (x) -> rectangleButton.Text <- "test").
And they did change the buttontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I spotted the problem:

when you do

```
let x = selectedTool
form.MouseDown
|> Event.add ( fun (evArgs1) -> 
    Something goes here
```

Inside the lambda x won't change.  You probably want to either get rid of the `let x = ...` before the lambda or use a ref cell like this:

```
let selectedTool  = ref Rectangle
```

then you assign with

```
selectedTool := Circle
```

and get the value with

```
if (!selectedTool) = Circle
```

Although a match would be more common - like so

```
form.MouseDown
|> Event.add ( fun (evArgs1) -> 
    match (!selectedTool) with
    |Circle -> graphics.Graphics.DrawEllipse(whitePen, evArgs1.X, evArgs1.Y, 15, 15)
    |Rectangle -> graphics.Graphics.DrawRectangle(whitePen, evArgs1.X, evArgs1.Y, 15,15)
    form.Refresh())
```

Comment: I changed selectedTool to a ref call and assigned my variables with := instead, And it works great!  
But I didnt manage to pull of the match. This is what I got so far:
`let mouseEvent = (newline)
    form.MouseDown = (newline)
        match selectedTool with (newline)
        | Ellipse -> Event.add( fun(evArgs) -> g.G.Draw(pen,x,y,w,h))(newline)
        | Rectangle -> g.G.Draw(pen, x, y, w, h)`

None of the above rows work would work.
I will mark as answer, but will be really glad if you could help me with the match.
Edit: added (newline) and code block for clarification